# CSS align text and image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div with 3 columns. In each div I have a text and an image. Is it possible to align the images on the same hight? Now the image is below the text, but the text length differs for each column. I'd like to have the images in the bottom of each column.

[image]

Thanks,

Carolin

```css
#content_row{
    margin-top:150px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;

}

#content_col{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
     transform: scale(0.8);
     -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
     transition: .3s ease-in-out;
     padding-bottom: 30px;



}
#content_col:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
     -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 50px black;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
     box-shadow:         0 0 50px black;
}

.tile-img{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    vertical-align: bottom;

}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="content_row">
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="content_col"><h3>Test</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
           <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/05/21/45/balloon-2921973_960_720.jpg" class="tile-img">
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="content_col"><h3>Test2</h3>
          <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
           <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/05/21/45/balloon-2921973_960_720.jpg" class="tile-img">
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="content_col"><h3>Test3</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
           <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/05/21/45/balloon-2921973_960_720.jpg" class="tile-img">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: one image says more than 1000 words ;) ... please add a screenshot and at least the responsible parts of your html css

Comment: I knew you'll just add the image. Create a [mcve], because a [mcve] says more than 100000000000 words and images

Comment: @woodii i just added a simple illustration of my problem. I would like to have the images aligned all to the bottom.

Comment: @AlonEitan added the code but running it doesn't display in a row...

Comment: @CarolinaPdw Now your question is absolutely great! Retracted my downvote into an upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

#content_row {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex;           /* add the following 2 styles */
  flex-direction: row;
}

#content_row>.col-sm-4 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  flex-grow: 1;                       /* add this to make the column grow to the height of the row */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content_row>.col-sm-4>p {
  flex-grow: 1;               /* add this to make the p take up all remaining space */
}
```

[Example bootply](https://www.bootply.com/nqCRVB1cAL)

You will also note that I have removed your ids from your columns - ids are meant to be unique

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.
#content_row>.col-sm-4>p {
  flex-grow: 1;               /* add this to make the p take up all remaining space */
} did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this but you have to use `flex-box`for this.
Give each column the property of `display: flex;` and set it's direction to `flex-direction: column`.
Wrap the text in an extra div and give it the property of `flex-grow: 1`.
To wrap it up:

HTML

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col col-md-4">…</div>     

  <div class="col col-md-4">
    <div class="text">
     <p>Text …</p>
    </div>
    <img src="path/to/img">
  </div>

  <div class="col col-md-4">…</div>     

</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: if I try to use your code, it shows all in one column and not in a row

Comment: Sure, you have to adjust your selectors in CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can add the height for `p` tag based on maximum character inside any column.

You also use `col-xs-*` instead of `col-sm-*` for very small display size support.

```css
#content_row{
    margin-top:150px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;

}

#content_col{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
     transform: scale(0.8);
     -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
     transition: .3s ease-in-out;
     padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#content_col:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
     -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 50px black;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
     box-shadow:         0 0 50px black;
}

.tile-img{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    float: top;

}
.p-text{
     height:500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="row" id="content_row">
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="content_col"><h3>Test</h3>
         <p class="p-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
           <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/05/21/45/balloon-2921973_960_720.jpg" class="tile-img">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="content_col"><h3>Test2</h3>
          <p class="p-text">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
           <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/05/21/45/balloon-2921973_960_720.jpg" class="tile-img">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="content_col"><h3>Test3</h3>
          <p class="p-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
           <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/05/21/45/balloon-2921973_960_720.jpg" class="tile-img">
     </div>
</div>
```